# How to show retrieved data from firebase to header tag <h1>{{ }}</h1> in vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

i have been trying to show retrieved data from firebase into  tag but does not display nothing.

I have retrieved data of current user from firestor. In Console log, it shows data correctly. But when i tried to assign value to header tag it does not show anything.

here is code i tried so :

```
 data() {
  return {

        email: '',
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        secondaryEmail: '',
        businessName: '',

  };

},
computed:{
  currentUser (){

    return this.$store.state.currentUser
  }
  },
methods: {

},

created() {

  const firestore = database.firestore(); 

  firestore.collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid). onSnapshot(function(doc){

          const newData = doc.data()

          console.log('newData:', newData.email)
          console.log('firstname:', newData.firstname)

          const email = newData.email;
          const firstname = newData.firstname;
          const lastname = newData.lastname;
          const secondaryEmail = newData.secondaryEmail;
          const businessName = newData.businessName;

          this.email = email;
          this.firstname = firstname;
          this.lastname = lastname,
          this.secondaryEmail = secondaryEmail,
          this.businessName = businessName


          console.log('profile email:',  this.email)
          console.log('profile firstname:',  this.firstname)
          console.log('profile lastname:',  this.lastname)
          console.log('profile secondaryEmail:',  this.secondaryEmail)
          console.log('profile businessName:',  this.businessName)



      })



}
```

Here is my html template where i am trying to pass email, firstname, lastname, businessname value which i got from firebase console output.

```
   <div class="card" style="border: none;">
                      <div class="card-body" style="float: left; text-align: left;" >
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{firstname}}</h5><br>
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{lastname}}</h5><br>
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{currentUser.email}}</h5><br>
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{secondaryEmail}}</h5><br>
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{businessName}}</h5><br>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Console log output result: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `function()` call inside onSnapshot has its own scope, so the `this` inside that function no longer refers to the component:

```
...onSnapshot(function(doc){...})
```

Instead use a fat arrow function, to preserve the component `this`:

```
...onSnapshot((doc) => {...})
```

(A secondary bug is that you're trying to display `{{currentUser.email}}` but setting `this.email`; you'll need to use the same variable name for both.)